# Sum and Multiplication of Matrices

Tags: matrices

It is possible to arrive at a multiplication result by summing, but is this also true for matrix multiplication?

Is it possible to arrive at the same matrix generated by matrix multiplication by summing matrices?

```
A = [2 3]   B = [1 2]   AxB = [11 19]
    [1 4]       [3 5]         [13 22]
```

What would the sum of matrix A be like with some matrices to get the same result as above?

Comment: Do you mean to find $A, B$ matrices such as $AB=A+B$?

Comment: Multiplication is repeated addition only when one of the factors is a nonnegative integer, so you can't replace multiplication by summation all the time even for real number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the multiplication of two or more matrices as sum of termwise product of matrices.

For example $$\begin {bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end {bmatrix} \begin {bmatrix} e&f\\g&h\end {bmatrix}=$$

$$ \begin {bmatrix} a&a\\c&c\end {bmatrix}\circ  \begin {bmatrix} e&f\\e&f\end {bmatrix}+\begin {bmatrix} b&b\\d&d\end {bmatrix}\circ \begin {bmatrix} g&h\\g&h\end {bmatrix}$$where the $\circ $ means term by term multiplication of matrices.

I am not quite conveinced that this is a better approach to the usual multiplication of matrices.

Comment: "*...where the dot means term by term multiplication of matrices*" so... a [hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))?  As I understand, that is usually denoted with a `\circ` or an `\odot`.

Comment: Thanks I try to fix the notation.

Comment: I may not have been clear, 2*3 = 2 + 2 + 2, but in matrix multiplications is it possible to add matrices to get the same result as multiplication?

Comment: @rafaelcb21 It works for scalar product , that is  $3A=A+A+A$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need to consider the elements of the matrix independently.  For example, take two $n$ x $n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, with $n^2$ elements $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$, respectively.  If $C=AB$, then $$c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}$$ where the term $a_{ik}b_{kj}$ is just scalar multiplication.  So if you are dealing with integers (which seems implicit in your question) you could think of each element as a sum of sums.